# Infinite scroll with API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, intersection-observer

I would like to make an infinite scroll with Intersection Observer that in the call back function increments the page number from an API and displays another image.

I am stuck on how I can call the API again and increment the page.

This is what I tried:

```
      const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
      const [images, setImages] = useState(null);
      const lastItem = useRef(null);

      useEffect(() => {
    const intersection = new IntersectionObserver(() => {
      // setPage(page + 1);
    });

    if (lastItem.current) {
      intersection.observe(lastItem.current);
    }
  

    });

      useEffect(() => {
        async function dataSet() {
          const data = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=${apiKey}&page=${page}`).then((res) => res.json());
          setImages(data);
        }
        dataSet();
      }, [apiKey, page]);

  useEffect(() => {});

  if (!images) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <main>
        <section className={styles.spacer}>
          <h1>Trending Movies</h1>
          <ul className={styles.grid}>
            {images.results?.map((image) => {
              return (
                <li className={styles.gridItem} key={image.id} ref={lastItem}>
                  <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w370_and_h556_bestv2/${image.poster_path}`} alt={image.name} />
                  <p className={styles.title}>{image.original_title}</p>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </section>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? Are you still using the same code or did you remove the "map" function or useState? Curious

Comment: This allows you to set the milliseconds, but this is for HTML, and I'm not sure how to adapt this to react or CSS https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1